# See reason why someone flagged as "unsalvageable" in triage

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, triage

After having the last "Looks OK" vote on triage questions, you will see a screen with previous reviewers and what they voted, as per this picture.

[image: Triage review result]

Quite often, even though a post looks OK in my opinion (and clearly enough others too) I find someone voted to close as unsalvageable. Mostly this has me wondering why they voted this, and if my review was appropriate considering it could be unsalvageable.

Would it be possible to add the reason they marked it as unsalvageable? Something like:

> [Plutian](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/11936678/plutian) reviewed this 8 minutes ago: **Unsalvageable** - Needs details or clarity

For this post, it won't do any good as the review is already completed. However it might give an insight to how other people review questions, and improve your reviews in the future. This would especially come in handy on more disputed posts with multiple votes in different directions.

Something to keep in mind, when shown this at the end of review, I would consider their review as wrong, since I reviewed different. However if I were to spot recurring reasons in my "Looks OK" reviews, I might change my opinion to agree with them more on similar questions in the future, and review more carefully.

*I had the link to above review here, but as someone in the comments pointed out, my review could indeed have been wrong, and the discussion about this would distract from my feature request. So I removed the link, but it does display my point: Without seeing the reason someone voted "Unsalvageable" I'd just dismiss them as wrong and would happily go along being wrong myself.*

Comment: @yivi I have removed the link. Although it does display my point, I could have been wrong in my review, and I would never have known why. Hence my request for more insight.

Comment: would be neat to also see the reason why one flagged Looks OK...

Comment: It does not need such an specific example, though. And being it there could focus some users in the incorrect review, and not on your feature request. There was even an answer posted to that effect. Just trying to help here. If you want to ask about for advise about your reviews, I'd open a different question about it.

Comment: @yivi I agree with your point, what I reviewed and why is ultimately irrelevant for this post. It's more about clarity. And it seems easy enough to implement as all "unsalvageable" votes come with a reason by default. This makes gnats suggestion harder, even though that would indeed be useful. Although I suppose the reason would ultimately always be "because it *does* look OK to me"

Comment: Well, it was the only reviewer that correctly predicted that the question was going to get closed.  Maybe he saw the comment from the [google-chrome-extension] expert, for one making it unnecessary to annotate the review vote.  Did you see it?